# replacing values in two dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries and I want to replace the values in the first dict once its keys is the same in the second dict. the first dict contains tokens and tags of a tagged text, and the second dict contains tokens and tags, and I want to replace the tags of the first dict with the tags of the second dict once the tokens are the same. This is the code I did

```
dic1 = {}
dic2 = {}

text1 = "he/s is/V a/p good/j man/n"
list1 = [('he', 'SUB'), ('is', 'V'), ('good', 'ADJ')]
```

This is the wanted output

```
  he/SUB is/V a/p good/ADJ man/n
```

With the dictionary I have unordered the data structures in the original text

Can someone know someway to update the tagged words in the original text without the loss of originale order of the words?

Comment: for starters, you probably want `d2 = dict(list1)` and then, `d1.update(d2)` probably does what you are looking for (although that part is not entirely clear)

Comment: What problem(s) do you have w/ your code?  Can you provide example(s) of how it should work and what it does instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for key in dic1.keys():
   if key in dic2.keys():
      dic1[key] = dic2[key]
```

EDIT: I saw your edit. I don't think you need two dictionaries for this at all. One dictionary alongwith an update method call (see comments) should suffice.